# How to enable HSDPA programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to enable or disable HSDPA connection programatically in Android?

If so, how to do that? I didn't find any API in TelephonyManager.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - please consider if these trivial edits you keep making are important enough to justify bumping old question back to the top of the queue.

Comment: Ooops, didn't know that was happening. I'll stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to enable Network(CDMA, 3G or HSDPS) programmatically as of now. As we know we can enable WiFi programatically.

But we can set the preferable network among Mobile / WiFi.

ConnectionManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectionManager.TYPE_MOBILE/TYPE_WIFI);

Unfortunately, it is not working for me. When I tried to set TYPE_MOBILE, I am getting Security Exception even if I had required permission in my manifest.

When I tried to set TYPE_WIFI, It is not throwing exception, but while getting network preference, I am getting "-1", means there is no preferred network(No Documentation, its my prediction).